# Bootstrap form not acting properly

Tags: bootstrap-4

I copied a login form example (HTML and CSS), everything looks fine except the form-outline of the input-label

code:

```
<section class="vh-100 gradient-custom">
    <div class="container py-5 h-100">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">
                <div class="card bg-dark text-white" style="border-radius: 1rem">
                    <div class="card-body p-5 text-center">
                        <div class="mb-md-5 mt-md-4 pb-5">
                                        <form action="/login" method="post">
                                            <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
                                                <input type="email" id="email" name="email"
                                                    class="form-control form-control-lg" />
                                                <label class="form-label" for="email">Email</label>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
                                                <input type="password" id="password" name="password"
                                                    class="form-control form-control-lg" />
                                                <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label>
                                            </div>    
                                            <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg px-5" type="submit">
                                                Login
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

How mine looks:

[image: how mine looks]

How it should look:

[image: how it should look]

Any ideas why?

Comment: Why should the label be placed on top of the input? Bootstrap does not support this as far as I know.

Comment: As @cloned mentioned I think you are mistaken - angular material offers that option though..

Comment: First of all there are much bigger differences than just the outline as you mentioned. Secondly most of those classes don't belong to bootstrap. And finally if the reference picture better showed the appearence also when the input has focus, it would be easier to accomodate a correct answer... but it's impossible so far. I was going to suggest using the `placeholder` attribute on the inputs to replace each label.. but the question isn't clear enough to go that straight

Comment: @DiegoDeVita I updated the question and added the entire `<section>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented the `<label>` elements and added the `placeholder` attribute to the inputs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#placeholder

> Valid for text, search, url, tel, email, password, and number, the
> placeholder attribute provides a brief hint to the user as to what
> kind of information is expected in the field. It should be a word or
> short phrase that provides a hint as to the expected type of data,
> rather than an explanation or prompt. The text must not include
> carriage returns or line feeds. So for example if a field is expected
> to capture a user's first name, and its label is "First Name", a
> suitable placeholder might be "e.g. Mustafa".
>
> Note: The placeholder attribute is not as semantically useful as other
> ways to explain your form, and can cause unexpected technical issues
> with your content. See Labels for more information.

**As another user also pointed out, this is not the best solution semantically speaking, it was just the quickest way to get there.**

But to be fair, I have to tell that the background showed in the picture with the expected result, showed a darker background for those inputs compared to the new snippet you shared (with white background).

So I added a rule to make the input darker... unfortunately the placeholder strategy has a side effect: its color is chosen by the browser a darker shade of font-color.

```css
/*
rule added to make the input bg dark
but the placeholder color is darker than white
*/
input {
  background: black !important;
  color: white !important;  
  outline-width: 1px !important;
  outline-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="vh-100 gradient-custom">
  <div class="container py-5 h-100">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">
        <div class="card bg-dark text-white" style="border-radius: 1rem">
          <div class="card-body p-5 text-center">
            <div class="mb-md-5 mt-md-4 pb-5">
              <form action="/login" method="post">
                <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    class="form-control form-control-lg"
                    placeholder="Email"/>
                  <!-- <label class="form-label" for="email">Email</label> -->
                </div>

                <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    id="password"
                    name="password"
                    class="form-control form-control-lg"
                    placeholder="Password" />
                  <!-- <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label> -->
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg px-5" type="submit">
                  Login
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**And here a solution that would better fit with accessibility requirements since the placeholder solution isn't suitable for screen readers, for example.**

```css
.box{
  padding: 5rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.field {
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: fit-content;    
  border: solid 2px gray;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.field > * {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.field > label {
  width: 5rem;
}

.field input{
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    
  <div class="field">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Even tough this is the accepted answer, this is not how this should be done. A placeholder is not a label and should only show example value for the input. Use a label for this kind of stuff to be semantically correct and also accessible-compliant. There are multiple ways on how to place a label inside an input field and handle different states.

Comment: @cloned Yes I agree with you despite I was the author of that awkward solution. But at the same time I think the label should always show up, also when the fields were filled. I didn't like the idea to show/hide a label inside an input form and the `placeholder` looked the quickest way to achieve that result shown in the picture. Yes I know it's semantically incorrect because a placeholder is supposed to be an example of the input as you said. I would invite you to write a better proposal, but I can't say if the OP will still be checking the question any time soon to change the correct answer.

Comment: I agree with you, label should always be visible, but it should never overlap with what the user typed into the input field. There are enough tutorials on how to do that already on the web, I won't add an answer here. I just wanted to point out the non-accessible compliant part of your answer for every future user who stumbles upon the question, because as you said, OP might not be checking here anyhow.

Comment: @cloned `label should always be visible, but it should never overlap` that would better rephrased replacing but with and. So in the end the point was the label shouldn't be removed and should always be visible. I added that version at the end of my answer trying my best to make it as close as possible to what the picture shown.

Comment: Thanks, english is not my main language so I use too many commas and wrong words from time to time. Also thank you for providing a neat example on how to show the label and still have an input that looks like the wanted one, really appreciate it.